# Macro for duplicates with conditions

Tags: excel, duplicates, countif, vba

I have some datas where there are multiple duplicates in column E and its dept no. in column S. What I want to do is, for any duplicate value in col E if the values of Col S are same, then it should retain the same value in the 1st duplicate and delete other duplicates. If the Col S values are not same, it should have the value as "18" in it. Eg

`Col E   Col S`    Ans
   `1515A      10`   Retain no changes
   `1515AA     12`   Retain as 1515AA in Col A and 12 as Col S
   `1515AA     12`   Delete
   `1515AA     12`   Delete
   `5151B       8`    Retain no changes
   `515BB       5`  Take 515BB with 18
   `515BB       3`  Delete

I have nearly 800-1500 line items. Can anyone help me with a macro. It will be very useful for me, instead of manually finding and deleting datas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
Sub EraseR()
    i = 1
    While Range("E" & i).Value <> ""
        If (Range("E" & i + 1).Value = Range("E" & i).Value) And (Range("S" & i + 1).Value = Range("S" & i).Value) Then
            Range(i + 1 & ":" & i + 1).Delete
        ElseIf (Range("E" & i + 1).Value = Range("E" & i).Value) And (Range("S" & i + 1).Value <> Range("S" & i).Value) Then
            Range(i + 1 & ":" & i + 1).Delete
            Range("S" & i).Value = 18
        Else
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. This macro worked for me. Sorry for the delay in reply. :)